# When two curves touch each other at a single point, are they called intersecting?

Tags: terminology, analytic-geometry, curves

When any two curves touch each other at a single point, are they called intersecting, or just called they are touching each other? Are these terms - intersecting curves and touching curves used interchangeably? Is there any difference between these terms?

Comment: I have voted close this question because I believe that it does not have an objective answer.  Different authors might use the two terms interchangeably, while others might make a distinction between the two terms, and there may be authors who would use only one of the two terms.  As currently phrased, the answer to this question is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @XanderHenderson You could say the same about any question about a definition.  We still have the 'terminology' tag, though.  It's a matter of convention, but I don't think it's off-topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An intersection between two curves is a point they both have in common. We say that two curves intersect if they have (at least) one point in common.

Two curves "touching" usually means they are intersecting and at the same time directions of the two curves at the point of intersection are exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you. By saying "directions of the two curves at the point of intersection are exactly the same", do you mean their derivates are same (as mentioned in the answer by @Peter)? Could you please explain this point further, as I've some issues in understanding that?

Comment: @Intellex Derivatives are somtething that functions have. Curves are not (in my view) functions, they are collections of points. But yeah, if the two curves happen to be the graphs of differentiable functions, then touching means both the values are equal (so that they intersect), and the deriatives are equal (so that they point in the same direction). A non-function example is that the curve given by all points $(x, y)$ with $x^2+y^2 = 1$ (a circle of radius $1$ centered at the origin) and the cure given by $(x-2)^2+y^2 = 1$ (a circle of radius $1$ centered at $(2, 0)$) touch at $(1,0)$.

Comment: Thank you. Can we say "touching" is a subset of "intersection"? Or in other words, all curves which "touch" are "intersecting" but the converse need not be true?

Comment: @Intellex I wouldn't call it "subset" quite like that, but yes. The same way "square" also implies "rectangle".

Comment: Thank you. How to know whether $y=|x|$ and $y=0$ are touching or intersecting at $x=0$?

Comment: Is the term "touching" an official term, as I am unable to find relevant information in Wikipedia and MathWorld?

Comment: @Intellex Clearly they are intersecting. I wouldn't say they are touching personally, but some may define "touching" in subtly different ways that makes it so that they are indeed touching.

Comment: @Intellex You have some information [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TangentCurves.html). "Tangent" is in my experience usually used specifically when one of the curves is a _line_, but apparently Wolfram uses it for other cases too.

Comment: Finally, tangent is "touching" or "intersecting", or both?

Comment: @Intellex "Tangent" is the same as touching. Which automatically implies intersecting.

Comment: Wikipedia says about Intersection Curves : "In geometry, an intersection curve is, in the most simple case, the intersection line of two non-parallel planes in Euclidean 3-space. In general, an intersection curve consists of the common points of two transversally intersecting surfaces, meaning that at any common point the surface normals are not parallel. **This restriction excludes cases where the surfaces are touching or have surface parts in common.** " So does this mean when curves touch they don't intersect, contrary to what we've discussed? Or is it advisable to leave this aside?

Comment: @Intellex I myself don't think so. I think intersection is any kind of having points in common, including touching. But you should have picked up by nw on the fact that the little details aren't the same for everyone. Some people insist that squares are not rectangles, and while I find it strange, I have to accept that that is a valid, if cumbersome, way to look at the world. Also, what you have there is about the intersection between _surfaces_, not between _curves_.

Comment: If you want to emphasize the two types of single-point intersections of curves in a plane, you could call one "touching" and the other "crossing."

Answer (score 3):

"Interesecting" at $x$ just means $$f(x)=g(x)$$ "Touching" at $x$ additionally means $$f'(x)=g'(x)$$

Comment: So, may I say, "touching" is a subset of "intersecting"?

Comment: You can say that "touching" is a stronger property than "intersecting" or the pairs of touching curves is a subset of the pairs of intersecting curves.

Comment: Thank you. If two curves are "intersecting" does it imply that they are not "touching"?

Comment: We call the curves "intersecting" , if they are just intersecting, but not touching. If they even touch, we should call them "touching" , but strictly speaking we could also call them "intersecting". It is best to formulate the strongest property that holds. As we call a square not a "rectangular" although it is one.

Comment: $f'(x)=g'(x)$ is not always true for two curves  "touching" at $x$. For example in some cases  of a curve having a cusp point at $x$.

Comment: @JJacquelin, So for curves like $y=|x|$ and $y=0$ how to say whether they are touching or intersecting at $x=0$?

Comment: @Intellex Then, you should have clarified what you mean with "curves". I assumed (differentiable) functions, but if you mean arbitary curves you should mention how they are defined, for example by a parametrization.

Comment: @Peter, I thought "curves" are general terms used, so I didn't mention it explicitly. I considered rules to be same before I saw the comment by JJacquelin. I realised only then this form cannot be applied to non-differentiable functions. My intention was on the geometrical aspect.

Comment: But what holds (also for arbitary curves) is that "touching" is stronger than "intersecting"

Comment: @Peter, Thank you. Now, I am a bit confused for non-differentiable functions $y=|x|$. How to tell whether it is touching or intersecting the $x$ axis?

Comment: In this case, it is just intersecting the x-axis because we have a function that is not differentiable at $0$. But this argument won't work in every case. If we have vertical tangents at both curves, they can touch as well.

Comment: So only differentiable curves can touch and intersect whereas non-differentiable curves can only intersect. Is it right to conclude this since non-differentiable curves don't obey the rule stated in the answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100520/discussion-between-peter-and-intellex).

Comment: @Intelellex. Your example $y=|x|$ and $y=0$ is typical. In fact the question is to have a standard definition for "intersecting" and for "touching". I doubt that the respective definitions be standardized, except in case of "intersection" in set theory. In sense of set theory the "intersection" is the subset commun to the two sets considered. In this sense considering the curves as sets of points, the intersection is the common point, so is the "touching" point in this particular case.

Answer (score 3):

Let me clarify [my above comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3416237/when-two-curves-touch-each-other-at-a-single-point-are-they-called-intersecting/3417084#comment7025997_3416244).

The discussion might be endless because there is no consensus on the definitions of "intersecting" and "touching".

One cannot give a definitive answer to the question raised until the definitions of these two words be clear and accepted by everybody.

Presently I doubt that the respective definitions be standardized, except in case of "intersection" in set theory.

In the set theory the "intersection" is well defined : That is the subset common to the two sets considered. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory) .

If this definition in set theory was extended to usual geometry the intersection of two curves would be the common part of the curves whatever the overall configuration and whatever the common part be one point only or many. But everybody can or not support this view.

I am not qualified for the standardization of mathematical vocabulary. Nevertheless I am allowed to give my own opinion which is :

- For geometry, generalize the definition of "intersection" well established in the set theory.
- And for geometry, standardize the definitions of some sub-cases such as "Crossing  intersection", "Touching intersection", etc.